# Storing email in keychain impossible (KeychainItemWrapper)

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, keychain

I'm using the ARCified version of KeychainItemWrapper available at [github](https://gist.github.com/1170641), and I can't get it to store both email and password.

```
KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"myApp" accessGroup:@"MY_APP.com.yourcompany.GenericKeychainSuite"];
    [keychainItem setObject:[self.email dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
    [keychainItem setObject:self.password forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
```

I works perfectly as long as I store an email... that don't have an at sign (@) it. Otherwise, I get the error

```
*** Assertion failure in -[KeychainItemWrapper writeToKeychain]
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't add the Keychain Item.'
```

Which comes from those lines

```
result = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)[self dictionaryToSecItemFormat:keychainItemData], NULL);
NSAssert( result == noErr, @"Couldn't add the Keychain Item." );
```

Do you have any idea about what can be going wrong here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Well, I just found the answer following the advice on that page [iOS KeychainItemWrapper not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054285/ios-keychainitemwrapper-not-updating), which is to add

```
[keychainWrapper setObject:@"Myappstring" forKey: (id)kSecAttrService];
```

Comment: KeychainItemWrapper was mostly working for me, worked on many email addresses (stored as username in kSecAttrAccount), but one email in particular did not work. I then added the above line for kSecAttrService and all is now perfect! -Thank you @user229688

Comment: Thanks user229688. It works perfectly after setting object for  kSecAttrService

Comment: Note that you have to set that before you set kSecAttrAccount and kSecValueData. Otherwise it will still crash.

Comment: How do retrieve this when next run of application?

Comment: I added that line of code before my line where I set kSecAttrAccount, and now it crashes on your line of code instead. Anyone else experiencing this?

Answer (score 1):

I know its an old question, but that was happening to me and the above answers did not fix my problem. In my case I was accessing the keychain when the phone was locked.
Finally I got to solve it by using this just after init the keychain.

```
keychainWrapper.setObject(kSecAttrAccessibleAlways, forKey: kSecAttrAccessible)
```

It seems that keychain does not let you access it unless your phone is unlocked, by default.

More info here : http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/using-the-keychain-to-store-passwords-on-ios/

Comment: Interesting thanks for the input, although it's not advisable to always use that since it's less secure