# KeychainItemWrapper 'Couldn't add the Keychain Item.'

Tags: ios, swift, keychainitemwrapper

I want to store access token to keychain. But i got the error: `Couldn't add the Keychain Item.'`

I checked some posts on stackoverflow like:
[Storing email in keychain impossible (KeychainItemWrapper)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886064/storing-email-in-keychain-impossible-keychainitemwrapper)

MyCode:

```
let a = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: "980a872c17a075367357e25e88c1c0476417092a")
let keyWrapper = KeychainItemWrapper.init(identifier: "23123123", accessGroup: nil)
keyWrapper?.setObject(a, forKey: kSecValueData)
```

1. I tried add this

   ```
   keyWrapper?.setObject(kSecAttrAccessible, forKey: kSecAttrAccessible)
   ```
2. Change `kSecValueData` to `kSecAttrGeneric`

I am running Xcode 8 with swift 3.0. Any hints thank you!

**EDIT**===========================

Viruss mca's answer turn on **Share keychain entitlement** just work once for me : (

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456471/secitemadd-always-returns-error-34018-in-xcode-8-in-ios-10-simulator?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I have recently face this issue with Xcode 8.

To solve the issue You have to add the "Share keychain entitlement" to Xcode capabilities.

[image]

There are many users who faced this issue.

Ref:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/60617

Comment: Hi Viruss, it's interesting. This just work for me once. I enabled it. And still same error now. I tried to add KeyChain Groups string into `accessGroup` parameter, still no help. Any idea?

Comment: @WilliamHu: where did you get this issue? on device?

Comment: Both simulator and device.

Comment: Sorry just for attention, i canceled the accept answer. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I only see this error in my simulator, on iOS 10 devices it runs fine. I'm very confused.

Comment: Thanks, save my time. :)

Answer (score -2):

OK, after struggle a long time i found i my Apple account was expired before i update to Xcode8. I solved it by removed my account then login again. And only for device not simulator.

Comment: The other answer about the Entitlements should really be the accepted answer.

Comment: Hi @KennyWyland i knew Viruss did provide a good solution, but it doesn't really solve my problem. I have up voted  for this answer. Thank you!

Comment: It didn't solve your problem, but was the reason for it, from the answers provided, was the best one