# Keychain data lost when upgrading the ios app

Tags: ios, upgrade, keychain, provisioning-profile, data-loss

My application is built using React Native. I am planning to release the new version of my app and currently testing the new release through TestFlight. Whenever I upgrade from the old app to this new app in testflight, old app data stored in the keychain gets deleted. The new application is not modifying anything related to keychain data.

I checked entitlements of both old and new IPA using the following command after unzipping the ipas -> codesign -d --entitlements :- "Payload/myApp.app". Entitlements are same for both apps.

I have also checked this link - [Keychain data lost after updating the app on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680459/keychain-data-lost-after-updating-the-app-on-ios). But answers are not applicable to me.

Additionally, I ran the following command ->
security cms -D -i "Payload/myApp.app/embedded.mobileprovision". I found that there is extra key added in the new app. It is. "DER-Encoded-Profile".

What could be possible reasons that the new app upgrade is deleting data?