# iOS Keychain occasionally return empty string

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, background, keychain

I write very secure application (for Bank) and I keep the private key in the Keychain.
I keep the Private key using the following code:

```
+(void)savePrivatekey:(NSString *)Key
{
    KeychainItemWrapper *keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"pKey" accessGroup:nil];
    [keychain setObject:Key forKey:(id)kSecValueData];
    [keychain release];
}
```

and for get the private key using the following code:

```
+(NSString *)privateKey
{
    KeychainItemWrapper *keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"pKey"accessGroup:nil];
    NSString *privateKey = [keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecValueData];
    [keychain release];
    return privateKey;
}
```

i don't save the private key in local variable from security reasons.
because every call to server I need the private key i call to to function
"GetPrivateKey" a lot of times.
Maybe that's why sometimes i get from the keychain empty string.
i can't  think of why this might happen.
I noticed that in most cases this happens when the application return from background but no only...
thanks...

I opened ticket at Apple's engineers and they responded to me:

Are you setting the kSecAttrAccessible attribute when you create the keychain item initially?

I always create the same shape keychain:
KeychainItemWrapper * keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier: @ "pKey" accessGroup: nil];

Does anyone know what their intent?
thanks...

Comment: Keeping a pointer in a local variable doesn't sound like a security problem to me...?

Comment: Me too, but still the instructions were not to keep the private key variable besides  in the keychain....

Comment: not strictly relevant, but naming your method `get...` doesn't follow Cococa naming conventions: `Use “get” only for methods that return objects and values indirectly. You should use this form for methods only when multiple items need to be returned.` https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html

Comment: I don't use ARC unfortunately,(Phonegap 1.7)

Comment: Here's a shot in the dark: [KeychainItemWrapper Not Updating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054285/ios-keychainitemwrapper-not-updating)

Answer (score 1):

I answered my own question a while back regarding this. I'm not sure if this is your exact problem as your code seems to look/work fine. So regarding your keychain access, I'm guessing it is a bit different. This may or may not help, but might steer you in the right direction.

[iOS KeyChain not retrieving values from background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536859/ios-keychain-not-retrieving-values-from-background/10583042#10583042)

Answer (score 0):

If your class is using ARC the following works for me every time.

```
KeychainItemWrapper *testKeychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"AppUniqueID" accessGroup:nil];
NSString *privateKey = [testKeychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];

NSLog(@"Private Key: %@ \n", privateKey);
```